# How do a make a login feature that retrieves the user from the database?

Tags: html, python-2.7, google-app-engine, backend, gqlquery

I am making a basic web page that has a sign up page and a login page. I am using google app engine, python, and HTML. This is my user function:

```
class User(db.Model):
    name = db.StringProperty(required=True)
    pw_hash = db.StringProperty(required=True)
    email = db.StringProperty()

    @classmethod
    def by_id(cls, uid):
        return cls.get_by_id(uid, parent=users_key())

    @classmethod
    def by_name(cls, name):
        u = cls.all().filter('name=', name).get()
        return u

    @classmethod
    def register(cls, name, pw, email=None):
        pw_hash = make_pw_hash(name, pw)
        return cls(parent=users_key(),
                    name=name,
                    pw_hash=pw_hash,
                    email=email)

    @classmethod
    def login(cls, name, pw):
        u = cls.by_name(name)
        if u and valid_pw(name, pw, u.pw_hash):
            return u
```

When I register new users, I put them in the database. They are being stored in the database:

```
class Register(Signup):
    def done(self):
        #make sure the user doesn't already exist
        u = User.by_name(self.username)
        if u:
            msg = 'That user already exists.'
            self.render('signup-form.html', error_username = msg)
        else:
            u = User.register(self.username, self.password, self.email)
            u.put()

            self.login(u)
            self.redirect('/blog')
```

But when I use my login function, I am unable to retrieve the user from the database to use the login feature. It says "login invalid" every time:

```
class Login(BlogHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.render('login-form.html')

    def post(self):
        username = self.request.get('username')
        password = self.request.get('password')

        u = User.login(username, password)
        if u:
            self.login()
            self.redirect('/blog')
        else:
            msg = 'Invalid login'
            self.render('login-form.html', error = msg)
```

When I signup, it's supposed to recognize that the User is already in the database. However, I am able to sign up with the same credentials every time. Here is my signup Handler:

```
class Signup(BlogHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.render("signup-form.html")

    def post(self):
        have_error = False
        self.username = self.request.get('username')
        self.password = self.request.get('password')
        self.verify = self.request.get('verify')
        self.email = self.request.get('email')

        params = dict(username = self.username,
                      email = self.email)

        if not valid_username(self.username):
            params['error_username'] = "That's not a valid username."
            have_error = True

        if not valid_password(self.password):
            params['error_password'] = "That wasn't a valid password."
            have_error = True
        elif self.password != self.verify:
            params['error_verify'] = "Your passwords didn't match."
            have_error = True

        if not valid_email(self.email):
            params['error_email'] = "That's not a valid email."
            have_error = True

        if have_error:
            self.render('signup-form.html', **params)
        else:
            self.done()

    def done(self, *a, **kw):
        raise NotImplementedError
```

Here is the bloghandler function which is the base line for all the other functions:

```
class BlogHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def write(self, *a, **kw):
        self.response.out.write(*a, **kw)

    def render_str(self, template, **params):
        params['user'] = self.user
        return render_str(template, **params)

    def render(self, template, **kw):
        self.write(self.render_str(template, **kw))

    def set_secure_cookie(self, name, val):
        cookie_val = make_secure_val(val)
        self.response.headers.add_header(
            'Set-Cookie',
            '%s=%s; Path=/' % (name, cookie_val))

    def read_secure_cookie(self, name):
        cookie_val = self.request.cookies.get(name)
        return cookie_val and check_secure_val(cookie_val)

    def login(self, user):
        self.set_secure_cookie('user_id', str(user.key().id()))

    def logout(self):
        self.response.headers.add_header('Set-Cookie', 'user_id=; Path=/')

    def initialize(self, *a, **kw):
        webapp2.RequestHandler.initialize(self, *a, **kw)
        uid = self.read_secure_cookie('user_id')
        self.user = uid and User.by_id(int(uid))
```

Here is the link to the GITHUB:

https://github.com/keldavis/registration

Here is the link to the website:

registration-148718.appspot.com

How do I make my signup page recognize an already created user? And how can I make my login page retrieve my user from the database and perform a valid login?

Answer (score 0):

Your line

`u = cls.all().filter('name=', name).get()`

should either be

`u = cls.all().filter('name =', name).get()`

or

`u = cls.all().filter('name', name).get()`

[per Google docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/queryclass#Instance_Methods) (note the missing space character / the `=` character being optional):

> **property_operator**:  String consisting of a property name and an optional comparison
>   operator (=, !=, <, <=, >, >=, IN), separated by a space: for example,
>   'age >'. If just a property name is specified without a comparison
>   operator, the filter compares for equality (=) by default.

*(also note that you should be using `google.appengine.ext.ndb` instead of `google.appengine.ext.db` and really shouldn't be implementing authentication / authorization / hashing / etc on your own in real apps)*